# how to create a matrix of financial returns in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix of asset prices

```
A,B
12.1,33.5
12.2,33.4
12.3,33.5
12.1,33.6
```

How can I get financial returns matrix using something like

```
RET(x) <- {(x-Previousx)/Previousx}  # My pseudocode
```

to give

```
A,B
0.0082,-0.0029
0.008197,0.0029
-0.0162,0.00298
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `diff()` with `apply()`:

```
dat <- read.csv(text="A,B
12.1,33.5
12.2,33.4
12.3,33.5
12.1,33.6", header=TRUE)
dat


apply(dat, 2, function(x)diff(x)/x[-length(x)])
                A            B
[1,]  0.008264463 -0.002985075
[2,]  0.008196721  0.002994012
[3,] -0.016260163  0.002985075
```

---

This works because:

1. The function `diff()` returns lagged differences
2. I then divide the results of `diff(x)` by `x[-length(x)]`, i.e. x after removing the last element. This ensures you divide the difference by the previous element.
3. Then simply wrap this into a `apply` that does this for each column.

Comment: Perhaps 2. should be x[-length(x)] as I wish to divide by previous asset value?

Answer (score 3):

Based on Andrie's answer but not need to use `apply` function

```
diff(as.matrix(dat)) / dat[-nrow(dat),]
             A            B
1  0.008264463 -0.002985075
2  0.008196721  0.002994012
3 -0.016260163  0.002985075
```

`diff` can be applied to a matrix, so simply converting `dat` into a matrix and applying `diff` will return the lagged differences for each column.

Answer (score 2):

```
dat <- read.csv(text = "A,B
12.1,33.5
12.2,33.4
12.3,33.5
12.1,33.6", header = TRUE)
```

Here is an easy and efficient way to do it:

```
(tail(dat, -1) - head(dat, -1)) / head(dat, -1)


             A            B
2  0.008264463 -0.002985075
3  0.008196721  0.002994012
4 -0.016260163  0.002985075
```